# How to fix error "raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)"

Tags: python, json, api, post, get

I'm trying to read data from json file by following code but i get error, any idea how to fix that?

```
file= open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Post.json",'r')
json_in=file.read()
request_json=json.loads(json_in)

print(request_json)
```

Json file

```
 "name": "Test",
 "job": "Programer"
```

Comment: your json file should like this @Moshe  {"name": "Test",
 "job": "Programer"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Post.json",'r')
request_json = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Please explain how you think this would solve the error while not knowing the content of the file.

Comment: Still not working...i get error  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) and when i replace to loads i get this error- raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: Gert Arlond I edited the question

Comment: @GertArnold It is under the assumption that the file has a mime-type of JSON no matter what the content is. If its in a JSON file it will be enclosed in {} this where the json.load() can be used

Comment: So after all, the content of the file was what made the difference.